# How to get window position of other program when the program is in expand monitor?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I want to detect whether a program is full screen in the expand monitor. I have got the expand monitor position using `EnumDisplayMonitors`. So if I get the program's position, I can compare it with expand monitor's position and get the result.

So I get the `HWND` of the program, and then I use `::GetWindowRect(HWND, &rect);` But the `rect` is not correct.

```
HWND g_HWND = NULL;
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProcMy(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    DWORD lpdwProcessId;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &lpdwProcessId);
    if (lpdwProcessId == lParam)
    {
        g_HWND = hwnd;
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

DWORD GetProcessidFromName(CString strName)
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe;
    DWORD id = 0;
    HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    pe.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    if (!Process32First(hSnapshot, &pe))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    pe.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    while (Process32Next(hSnapshot, &pe) != FALSE)
    {
        CString strTmp = pe.szExeFile;
        if (strName.CompareNoCase(strTmp) == 0)
        {
            id = pe.th32ProcessID;
            break;
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
    return id;
}

CRect rect[2] = { (0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0) }; //rect[1] stores the expand monitor's position

BOOL CALLBACK Monitorenumproc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData)
{
    static BOOL first = FALSE;

    MONITORINFO monitorinfo;
    monitorinfo.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFO);
    GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, &monitorinfo); 
    if (monitorinfo.dwFlags == MONITORINFOF_PRIMARY) 
    {
        if (!first) 
        {
            first = TRUE;
            rect[0] = monitorinfo.rcMonitor;
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            first = FALSE;
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        rect[1] = monitorinfo.rcMonitor;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

...
//get the position of xxx.exe
EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, Monitorenumproc, 0);
EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProcMy, GetProcessidFromName(_T("xxx.exe")));
RECT rect1;
::GetWindowRect(g_HWND, &rect1); //rect1 is not correct!
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by

> But the rect is not correct.

but here is what I see may seem incorrect:

1. Negative values, which indicate the window position relative to the primary display. You have to do the `[right-left, bottom-top]` calculation to get the size.
2. Values larger than the display size which means the rect `includes the area occupied by the drop shadow.`
   See the documentation of [GetWindowRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect)

> In Windows Vista and later, the Window Rect now includes the area
> occupied by the drop shadow.
>
> Calling GetWindowRect will have different behavior depending on
> whether the window has ever been shown or not. If the window has not
> been shown before, GetWindowRect will not include the area of the drop
> shadow.
>
> To get the window bounds excluding the drop shadow, use
> DwmGetWindowAttribute, specifying DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS. Note
> that unlike the Window Rect, the DWM Extended Frame Bounds are not
> adjusted for DPI. Getting the extended frame bounds can only be done
> after the window has been shown at least once.

So use the snippet below to get the size without the drop shadow:

```
RECT dwmExtFrameBounds;
DwmGetWindowAttribute(g_HWND, DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE::DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS, &dwmExtFrameBounds, sizeof(RECT));
```

Bonus read: [Why does a maximized window have the wrong window rectangle?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120326-00/?p=8003)